# Help the Rebels Stop Bomb Attacks in the Year 2078!

Tags: number-sequence

AUGUST 2078: ACCOUNT BY BOBBY SMITH OF THE SOUTHWESTERN EUROPEAN EMPIRE

Rebel armies moving forward. The robots have struck a city in Portugal State. The Imperial Soldiers have sent more attacks. Our spies have discovered the next attack will be in Southeastern Spain Province.

SEPTEMBER 2078: ACCOUNT BY [CLASSIFIED] OF NORTHERN FRANCE

The Rebels in the Southwestern European Empire are striking back. I have traced the bases that the Empire has sent the bombers from. They seem to use a specific pattern:

> Base 53
>
> Base 6F
>
> Base 75
>
> Base 74
>
> Base 68
>
> Base 77
>
> Base 65

NOVEMBER 2078: ACCOUNT BY CAPTAIN ARCHER OF THE SOUTHWESTERN EUROPEAN EMPIRE

Launch tomorrow: 18,000N, 4,000B, 82,000C. Prepare bombers at Base __. We will destroy the Rebels.

NOVEMBER 2078: LETTER FROM [CLASSIFIED] TO BOBBY SMITH

Large attack heading out soon. I intercepted a message from a captain. The base code was scribbled out. Please use previous info to find the base that will be sending the attack. Commander S. will supply weaponry to destroy the base.

YOUR MISSION

As the Rebel Cryptoanalyst, you must find the base that will send an attack next. Otherwise, the Southwestern European Empire may take over the world!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next base to be attacked will be:

> Base 73

The pattern is:

> The base numbers that they have attacked are hexadecimal ASCII values for "Southwe". Inferring that they will spell "Southwestern European Empire", the next letter is lowercase 's', which has hex ASCII value 73.